# Socket IO server being broken?

Tags: socket.io

I can't tell if this is a bug on my side or not, but I just can't figure out why this is not working.

Running a basic nodejs server and on a test page on nextjs, socket io is working perfectly fine. However, when I'm using it on my actual page, it does constant polling and never starts the ws connection, and the events don't work. The polling does have an appropriate response, with "upgrades":["websocket"] and all.

And, it seems that after the constant polling on that broken page starts, then the test page also starts doing it and doesn't work unless I restart my nodejs server. If I navigate to the broken page from the test page through nextjs, it also works, but a refresh then breaks it again. Any reason why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this script. This is my personal working script for socket IO chat app.

Backend Server

```
require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.SOCKET_PORT || 3000;
const main_server_url = process.env.SERVER_URL;
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(port);
var connectionOptions = {
  "force new connection": true,
  "reconnection": true,
  "reconnectionDelay": 2000,                  //starts with 2 secs delay, then 4, 6, 8, until 60 where it stays forever until it reconnects
  "reconnectionDelayMax": 60000,              //1 minute maximum delay between connections
  "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity",         //to prevent dead clients, having the user to having to manually reconnect after a server restart.
  "timeout": 10000,                           //before connect_error and connect_timeout are emitted.
  "transports": ["websocket"]                 //forces the transport to be only websocket. Server needs to be setup as well/
}
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server, connectionOptions);
var axios = require("axios");

var users = [];
var connections = [];

console.log("Server connected done");

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
  var server_url = main_server_url;
  console.log(server_url);

  console.log(people);
  connections.push(socket);
  console.log("Connected : total connections are " + connections.length);

  // rest of events of socket
});
```

Front End JS for load IO for client

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var base_url = YOUR_BASE_URL;
    var port = YOUR_SOCKET_PORT;
    var socket_port_url = base_url + ":" + port;
    var socket = io(socket_port_url);
    socket.on('done', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```